# Excel: How to prevent rounding off of cell in display which does not affect the data validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have format my cell to 3 digits with 2 decimal places. If I entered 9.999, it automatically rounds off to 10.00 on display. I cannot convert it to text for I need to put data validation on it ( valid range from 0 to 999.99 ) How will I turn off the rounding off the cell?

Comment: Do you still need it as 9.999, or can it be changed to 9.990?

Comment: You'll need two separate cells.  Use @CallumDS33's formula in the "display" cell; use your desired value in the cell for calculation.

Answer (score 2):

The `TRUNC()` function truncates numbers - i.e. cuts them off without rounding. Therefore:

`=TRUNC(9.999,2)` = 9.99